# Can not download .publishsettings from given link

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I want to install DDN with Azure Accelerator Wizard 6.3 for Windows Azure.
I am failing at the beginning, because the wizard want me to give a publishsettings-file.
Because I do not have one locally I wanted to download one at "Download Publish Settings File" and I am coming to https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx

When I want to click "here" nothing happens.
Also I do not exactly understand what this file should include, maybe I can write it by myself?

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at DotNetNuke on Windows Azure Web Sites?  It's probably an easier setup.

As for the publishsettings file, after you authenticate with your Microsoft Account, your browser should automatically prompt you to download the file.  The .publishsettings file contains a base64 encoded certificate used for managing all the Windows Azure subscriptions associated with your Microsoft Account.  It also contains a listing (name and subscription ID) of all your subscriptions.  Access that URL, besides generating the .publishsettings file, will create the management cert for you in Windows Azure for all your subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for quick answering!

I could not find anything on the Windows Azure Web Site - would you be so kind and post a link?

And I am logged in with my account, but my browser did nothing.

regards.

Comment: Main page for Windows Azure web sites is at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/.  Have a look at the "Open Source Apps" video.